# How to Make Microsoft Test Manager and Clear quest synchronized

Tags: mstest, test-report

I am trying nowadays to make both MTM & clear quest "ALM" synchronized in other words I am trying to import defects to MTM and also when trying to add a new one will sync to Clear quest directly and also  can see defects on MTM and when generating a report from MTM Can see both test cases and defects submitted and their status. 
I tried Integration tool but i didn't reach a good result.

Comment: what is your aim?  Do you wish to migrate from one to the other or do you plan to run two systems and attempt to keep them in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearQuest is owned by HP, so they make it easy to integrate with HP's suite of tools. There is, at least, an [API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.schema.ec.doc/topics/c_using_cq_api.htm). I did find [a tool by Kovair](http://www.kovair.com/adapters/clearquest-integration/) that might be the tool you need. It acts as an integration bus between MTM/TFS and ClearQuest.

Comment: I am investigating the tool nowadays and I think it will be useful, but if you know an opensource tool please tell me

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of one. You could use the API documentation to make your own bus, but it's probably faster and cheaper just to buy one of the shelf.